# How to update the comment text of a GitHub Pull Request Review using the API

Tags: git, github, github-api

Using the web UI of GitHub, you can edit the review summary of a PR review, for example as in this screenshot (see the pencil icon with the "Edit review summary" tooltip):

[image: Example PR review]

How to do this using the GitHub API?

I looked through the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/) but couldn't find a way to do this. I monitored the web service calls triggered on the page while making the change using the UI, I found a call to `https://api.github.com/repos/SonarSourceIT/pr-decoration/pull/3195/reviews/91117155/update`, so I tried to do the same using `curl`:

```
$ curl -sL -u janos-ss:$token  https://api.github.com/repos/SonarSourceIT/pr-decoration/pull/3195/reviews/91117155/update -X POST -d @comment.json | jq . | tee response.json 
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

I'm not surprised this didn't work, as the URL doesn't look like any of the documented API methods.

Note that this is not the same as editing a comment. Editing a comment is possible ([documented here](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#edit-a-comment)), but I want to edit the *review summary*, which is something else.

Is this possible to do using the [REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/)? I'm not interested in hacky solutions or using Selenium or similar. I'm looking for a clean API solution, or confirmation that this is in fact not possible with the current REST API v3.

**Update**

As confirmed by GitHub support, this is not possible using the REST API v3 as of today. (I confirm the suggestion in the accepted answer works, I will probably use that as a workaround.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to update pull request review using [updatePullRequestReview](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/updatepullrequestreview/) :

- a query to find review by pull request number & get reviews id
- a mutation to perform `updatePullRequestReview`

You can test the following in [the GraphQL explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=query%20FindReview%20%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22bertrandmartel%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22speed-test-lib%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pullRequest(number%3A%2046)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20reviews(first%3A%20100)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Amutation%20UpdateReview%20%7B%0A%20%20updatePullRequestReview(input%3A%20%7BpullRequestReviewId%3A%20%22MDE3OlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0UmV2aWV3OTExNjM5NjI%3D%22%2C%20body%3A%20%22some%20test%22%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pullRequestReview%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20updatedAt%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) :

```graphql
query FindReview {
  repository(owner: "bertrandmartel", name: "speed-test-lib") {
    pullRequest(number: 46) {
      reviews(first: 100) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

mutation UpdateReview {
  updatePullRequestReview(input: {pullRequestReviewId: "MDE3OlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0UmV2aWV3OTExNjM5NjI=", body: "some test"}) {
    pullRequestReview {
      updatedAt
    }
  }
}
```

You can find additionnal info about forming graphql call [here](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/)

The following script uses [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to request the list of  reviews, extract the first one & update the review body :

```bash
owner="SonarSourceIT"
name="pr-decoration"
pr=3195
access_token="YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"

# find reviews for PR - extract the first review ID
review_id=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Token $access_token" \
     -d '{ "query": "query  { repository(owner: \"'$owner'\", name: \"'$name'\") { pullRequest(number: '$pr') { reviews(first: 100) { edges { node { id } } } } } }" }' \
     https://api.github.com/graphql | \
     jq -r '.data.repository.pullRequest.reviews.edges[0].node.id')

curl -s -H "Authorization: Token $access_token" \
     -d '{ "query": "mutation { updatePullRequestReview(input: {pullRequestReviewId: \"'$review_id'\", body: \"some test2\"}) { pullRequestReview { updatedAt } } }" }' \
     https://api.github.com/graphql
```

Note that you can also update pull request review comment using [updatePullRequestReviewComment](https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/updatepullrequestreviewcomment/)

Comment: This is neat, and indeed it works, thanks (+1). I wasn't aware of the GraphQL API. I'm looking for a solution using the [REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/), or confirmation that it's not possible with that.

Comment: I got confirmation from GitHub support that this is indeed not possible today with the REST API v3. I will probably use your suggestion as a workaround. Thanks!